# nodejs and jade, object is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, drywall

I'm using node js, jade, and drywall (account management system) and I'm including a `stripe` script in my `views/signup/index.jade` file, like this:

```
extends ../../layouts/default

block head
  title Sign Up

block neck
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/views/signup/index.min.css?#{cacheBreaker}')

block feet
  script(src='/views/signup/index.min.js?#{cacheBreaker}')
  script(src='src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"')
  script
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_4ZVxtJ6e1uJJxWi2L6QWL8Hq');
```

And in my `public/views/index.js` file I'm calling this function

```
Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
```

However, I get the error `Stripe is not defined.` (meaning that the `Stripe script` I imported isn't being acccesed in the file that I'm in). So I thought to move the script tag to my `layouts/default.jade` file and put it in the head so it would appear in the head of every document, but still no luck. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to execute your script client-side, right ? If that's the case, you need to add a `.` (dot) after your `script` tag, so Jade does not try to parse your expression and leaves it for the browser to interpret.

So your code should be `script.
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_4ZVxtJ6e1uJJxWi2L6QWL8Hq')`

Comment: @WaldoJeffers yes, but the script that needs to be included is this part: `script(src='src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"')`. That is what contains the stripe object, this part (`Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_4ZVxtJ6e1uJJxWi2L6QWL8Hq')`) is just used to setup the already existing stripe object

Comment: it's saying that the Stripe object doesn't exist which means my JS file is not accessing it for some reason

Comment: Ok, when you say that you get a `Stripe is not defined` error message, is it client-side or server-side ?

And by the way, your script URL is wrong, you wrote the `src` attribute twice.
It should be `script(src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/")`.